# Getting individual sprites from png sprite sheets?

Tags: sprites

I'm using BYOB platform to get started in basic game development.

I was going to make a quick endless runner with a sprite downloaded from the net.

However, those sprites all come in sprite sheets, I guess for animation purposes.  I only need one sprite, can I extract that from the sheet with Gimp or Inkscape?

Comment: Can't you just crop the image down?

Comment: Remember these images are copyrighted and you might get some problems for publishing a game with them without author's (or owner's) permission, especially if you will make any money on the game. Also, are you this guy on left, or the lady on right?

Comment: I'm the lucky man on the left here.  I'll be doing this just to learn game programming.  Aside from getting friends to play test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprite Sheets, despite the name, are really only static images. That is to say, there's no hidden stacking or frames, so when you want to get just one sprite from a sprite sheet, the simplest way to do so is to crop the image to what you need.

Animation comes from changing which sprite is displayed over time, and oftentimes the way to do this is to assign one png (the sprite sheet) for the object's texture, and then limit which part of the texture is actually displayed, rather than have a separate PNG for each different frame.